# CreateRemoteThread runs with no error but nothing happens

Tags: c#, c++, memory, process

I'm trying to inject a C++ dll into a process and I'm using a C# console application to run it. My problem is that the program runs through but nothing appears to happen, the write succeeds and no win32 errors are raised.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var bootstrapperSettingsFilePath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "bootstrapperSettings.json");
        var bootstrapperSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BootstrapperSettings>(File.ReadAllText(bootstrapperSettingsFilePath));

        var startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();

        CreateProcess(
            bootstrapperSettings.TargetPath,
            null,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            false,
            ProcessCreationFlag.CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null, 
            ref startupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var processHandle = Process.GetProcessById((int)processInfo.dwProcessId).Handle;
        var loaderPath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "Loader.dll");
        var loaderPathPtr = VirtualAllocEx(
            processHandle, 
            (IntPtr)0, 
            loaderPath.Length, 
            MemoryAllocationType.MEM_COMMIT, 
            MemoryProtectionType.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error > 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to allocate memory for Loader.dll, error code: {error}");
        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(loaderPath);
        var bytesWritten = 0;
        WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, loaderPathPtr, bytes, bytes.Length, ref bytesWritten);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error > 0 || bytesWritten == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to write Loader.dll into the process, error code: {error}");

        var loaderDllPointer = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error > 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to get memory address to Loader.dll in the process, error code: {error}");

        CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)0, loaderDllPointer, loaderPathPtr, 0, (IntPtr)null);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error > 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to create remote thread to start execution of Loader.dll in the process, error code: {error}");

        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, loaderPathPtr, 0, MemoryFreeType.MEM_RELEASE);
    }
}
```

And the C++. This is responsible for calling a method on a WPF application and initialising it once the CLR is up and running. I would expect to at least hit one of the messagebox calls in this but nothing is presented.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define FOR_DOTNET_4
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#ifdef FOR_DOTNET_4
#include <metahost.h>
#else
#include <mscoree.h>
#endif
#include "CorError.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "mscoree" )

#define LOAD_DLL_FILE_NAME L"InjectionTest1.exe"
#define NAMESPACE_AND_CLASS L"InjectionTest1.Loader"
#define MAIN_METHOD L"Load"
#define MAIN_METHOD_ARGS L"NONE"

HMODULE g_myDllModule = NULL;

ICLRMetaHostPolicy* g_pMetaHost = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeInfo* g_pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeHost* g_clrHost = NULL;

HANDLE g_hThread = NULL;
wchar_t* dllLocation = NULL;

#define MB(s) MessageBoxW(NULL, s, NULL, MB_OK);

unsigned __stdcall ThreadMain(void* pParam)
{
    MB(L"Test");
    HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHostPolicy, IID_ICLRMetaHostPolicy, (LPVOID*)&g_pMetaHost);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MB(L"Could not create instance of ICLRMetaHost");
        return 1;
    }
    
    DWORD pcchVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwConfigFlags = 0;

    hr = g_pMetaHost->GetRequestedRuntime(METAHOST_POLICY_HIGHCOMPAT,
        dllLocation, NULL,
        NULL, &pcchVersion,
        NULL, NULL,
        &dwConfigFlags,
        IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo,
        (LPVOID*)&g_pRuntimeInfo);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == E_POINTER)
        {
            MB(L"Could not get an instance of ICLRRuntimeInfo -- E_POINTER");
        }
        else if (hr == E_INVALIDARG)
        {
            MB(L"Could not get an instance of ICLRRuntimeInfo -- E_INVALIDARG");
        }
        else
        {
            wchar_t buff[1024];
            wsprintf(buff, L"Could not get an instance of ICLRRuntimeInfo -- hr = 0x%lx -- Is DomainManager.dll present?", hr);
            MB(buff);
        }

        return 1;
    }
    
    hr = g_pRuntimeInfo->BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MB(L"Failed to bind as legacy v2 runtime! (.NET 3.5 Mixed-Mode Support)");
        return 1;
    }

    hr = g_pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID*)&g_clrHost);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MB(L"Could not get an instance of ICLRRuntimeHost!");
        return 1;
    }

    hr = g_clrHost->Start();

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MB(L"Failed to start the CLR!");
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    hr = g_clrHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(dllLocation, NAMESPACE_AND_CLASS, MAIN_METHOD, MAIN_METHOD_ARGS, &dwRet);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MB(L"Failed to execute in the default app domain!");


        switch (hr)
        {
        case HOST_E_CLRNOTAVAILABLE:
            MB(L"CLR Not available");
            break;

        case HOST_E_TIMEOUT:
            MB(L"Call timed out");
            break;

        case HOST_E_NOT_OWNER:
            MB(L"Caller does not own lock");
            break;

        case HOST_E_ABANDONED:
            MB(L"An event was canceled while a blocked thread or fiber was waiting on it");
            break;

        case E_FAIL:
            MB(L"Unspecified catastrophic failure");
            break;

        default:
            char buff[128];
            sprintf(buff, "Result is: 0x%lx", hr);
            MessageBoxA(NULL, buff, "Info", 0);
            break;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void LoadClr()
{
    wchar_t buffer[255];
    if (!GetModuleFileNameW(g_myDllModule, buffer, 255))
        return;

    std::wstring modulePath(buffer);
    modulePath = modulePath.substr(0, modulePath.find_last_of('\\') + 1);
    modulePath = modulePath.append(LOAD_DLL_FILE_NAME);
    dllLocation = new wchar_t[modulePath.length() + 1];
    MB((modulePath).c_str());
    wcscpy(dllLocation, modulePath.c_str());
    dllLocation[modulePath.length()] = '\0';

    g_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadMain, NULL, 0, NULL);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    g_myDllModule = hDll;
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        MB(L"Loading");
        LoadClr();
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        if (g_clrHost)
        {
            g_clrHost->Stop();
            g_clrHost->Release();
        }
        
        if (g_hThread)
        {
            TerminateThread(g_hThread, 0);
            CloseHandle(g_hThread);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The imports:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Bootstrapper
{
    static class WinImports
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            ProcessCreationFlag dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hHandle, UInt32 dwMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr dwAddress,
            int nSize,
            MemoryAllocationType dwAllocationType,
            MemoryProtectionType dwProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
            byte[] lpBuffer,
            int dwSize,
            ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttribute,
            IntPtr dwStackSize,
            IntPtr lpStartAddress,
            IntPtr lpParameter,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpThreadId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr dwAddress,
            int nSize,
            MemoryFreeType dwFreeType);

        internal enum MemoryAllocationType
        {
            MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
        }

        internal enum MemoryProtectionType
        {
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
        }

        internal enum MemoryFreeType
        {
            MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000
        }

        internal enum ProcessCreationFlag
        {
            CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000
        }

        internal struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public uint cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your injector code has many problems:

- leaking the `HANDLE`s output by `CreateProcess()` (which you can use instead of `Process.GetProcessById()`) and `CreateRemoteThread()`.
- not allocating enough bytes in the remote process to hold the `loaderPath` string, and not copying enough bytes into the remote process anyway.  You need to multiply `loaderPath.Length` by 2 (the size of a `System.Char`) when allocating the memory.  A better solution is to call `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` before calling `VirtualAllocEx()` and then allocate `bytes.length` number of bytes.  However, note that `LoadLibraryW()` requires a null-terminated string, but you are not copying a null terminator into the remote process.
- not waiting for `LoadLibraryW()` to actually finish running (ie, for the remote thread to terminate) before freeing the allocated memory.
- incorrect error handling.
- the calls to `Thread.Sleep()` are unnecessary and should be removed.

Try something more like this instead:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var bootstrapperSettingsFilePath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "bootstrapperSettings.json");
        var bootstrapperSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BootstrapperSettings>(File.ReadAllText(bootstrapperSettingsFilePath));

        var startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();

        if (!CreateProcess(
            bootstrapperSettings.TargetPath,
            null,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            false,
            ProcessCreationFlag.CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null, 
            ref startupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to start process, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
        }

        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

        try
        {
            var loaderPath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "Loader.dll") + "\0";
            var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(loaderPath);

            var loaderPathPtr = VirtualAllocEx(
                processInfo.hProcess,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                bytes.Length,
                MemoryAllocationType.MEM_COMMIT,
                MemoryProtectionType.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

            if (loaderPathPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to allocate memory for Loader.dll, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");

            try
            {
                var bytesWritten = 0;
                if (!WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, loaderPathPtr, bytes, bytes.Length, ref bytesWritten))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to write Loader.dll path into the process, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
                }

                if (bytesWritten != bytes.Length)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to write all bytes of Loader.dll path into the process");

                var loaderDllPointer = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

                if (loaderDllPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to get memory address to Loader.dll in the process, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");

                var hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(
                    processInfo.hProcess,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    0,
                    loaderDllPointer,
                    loaderPathPtr,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero);

                if (hRemoteThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to create remote thread to start execution of Loader.dll in the process, error code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
                }

                WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
                CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
            }
            finally
            {
                VirtualFreeEx(processInfo.hProcess, loaderPathPtr, 0, MemoryFreeType.MEM_RELEASE);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

That said, your C++ DLL is also [doing things it shouldn't be doing in `DllMain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: Thank you. Using the above example with a few minor changes I now no longer pass the C# portion but instead get:

Failed to create remote thread to start execution of Loader.dll in the process, error code: 0

Comment: Reading CreateRemoteThread, it sounds like the if check that throws the above exception is actually invalid as I'm not passing a pointer as the lpThreadId so nothing will be returned.

Unfortunately, removing that gets me to the same result i.e. the C# app ending with no interaction from the C++ portion.

Comment: The `lpThreadId` parameter of `CreateRemoteThread()` is optional and can be null. You should not be getting error code 0, though. What does your `DLLImport` declaration of `CreateRemoteThread()` look like, and does it have `SetLastError=true` set on it?

Comment: I've added the imports to my original post.

Comment: @JamieBrunton most of your `DllImport` statements do not have `SetLastError=true` specified, so `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` won't work when calling those functions. You need to fix that, then you should get a real error code when `CreateRemoteThread()` fails.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Remy Lebeau. When adding the SetLastError=true on the imports, I now get an error of 5 when the program reaches WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: @JamieBrunton error 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. But the code shown is not doing error handling on `WaitForSingleObject()`, so how do you know that is the function that is failing? It is unlikely to fail if `CreateRemoteThread()` is successful.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone through the steps and found the final problem was a lack of admin access. Everything is working fine now and the injected .net application is executing!

Thank you.